# CDK CICD Pipeline not finding references in stack to deploy

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I'm attempting to implement a cdk cicd pipeline for an app which I have already written the cdk stack for and the main app stack deploys fine manually with cdk deploy.  I am trying to get a cdk pipeline to automatically deploy the stack when changes are checked into main so its not a manual process

I have been following a combination of this [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html) tutorial and [this](https://cristianmagana.dev/blog/aws-cdk-pipeline-package/) blog which has got me pretty far

My folder structure is such:

[image]

The stack I wish to deploy via the pipeline is in lib/tagworx-rfid-cdk-stack.ts

Running cdk deploy from the root folder deploys this with no issues.

The CICD Pipeline stack is in /infra/lib.

Doing cdk deploy from there worked for a very simple test but when I added what I hoped would deploy the stack, I get the following error:

Error: Cannot find asset at root/infra/lib/resources/layers/helper.
I think this issue relates to the layer I have in the main stack I want the CICD pipeline to deploy, and that when it tries to do the lambda.Code.fromAsset('resources/layers/helper') the process is somehow still in the cicd location not the main stack location, so it obviously cannot find the reference

lib/tagworx-rfid-cdk-stack.ts - this is the stack I want the CICD pipeline to deploy

```
export class TagworxRfidCdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const layer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, 'HelperLayer', {
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('resources/layers/helper'),
      description: 'Axios and other helper functions',
      compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X],
    });
...
```

/infra/lib/infra-stack.ts

```
export class InfraStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineAppProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const buildCodeArtifactPolicy: PolicyStatement[] = [
      // some policies removed for brevity
    ];

    const buildEnvironmentForStep: BuildEnvironment = {
      computeType: ComputeType.SMALL,
      buildImage: LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_6_0,
      privileged: true,
    };

    const branch = 'main'

    const codeBuildStepSynth = new CodeBuildStep(`${props.name}-build-step`, {
      input: CodePipelineSource.connection(`${props.ghRepository}`, branch, {
        connectionArn: props.codestarConnectionArn,
      }),
      installCommands: ["npm install -g npm@latest"],
      commands: ["npm install", "npm run build", "npx cdk synth" ],
      rolePolicyStatements: buildCodeArtifactPolicy,
      buildEnvironment: buildEnvironmentForStep,
      primaryOutputDirectory: "cdk.out",
    });

    const codeBuildStepArtifact = new CodeBuildStep(
      `${props.name}-artifact-publish-step`,
      {
        commands: [
          "npm ci",
        ],
        rolePolicyStatements: buildCodeArtifactPolicy,
        buildEnvironment: buildEnvironmentForStep,
      }
    );


    
    const pipeline: CodePipeline = new CodePipeline(
      this,
      `${props?.name}-code-pipeline`,
      {
        pipelineName: `${props.name}-pipeline`,
        selfMutation: true,
        synth: codeBuildStepSynth,
      }
    );
    
    const env = { account: '1111111111', region: 'eu-west-1' };
    const stackName = `dev-rfid-stack-${env.region}`;
    
    // THIS  is what has broken the cdk deploy, without this it deploys the cicd pipeline,
    // but I think I need this to actually deploy the stack?
    pipeline.addStage(new InfraAppStage(this, stackName, {
      env: env
    }));

    pipeline.addWave(`${props.name}-code-artifact-publish`, {
      post: [codeBuildStepArtifact],
    });
    
    pipeline.buildPipeline();
  }
}
```

/infra/lib/infra-app-stage

```
export class InfraAppStage extends cdk.Stage {

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StageProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);

      const lambdaStack = new TagworxRfidCdkStack(this, 'my-test-stack');
    }
}
```

When the additional app stage is added:

```
pipeline.addStage(new InfraAppStage(this, stackName, {
      env: env
    }));
```

and I attempt to deploy I end up with the error.

Its looking in the cicd folder for the references in the actual stack I want to deploy?

I was expecting that the references would know where they were?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full path to the Lambda code file:

```js
import path from "path";
//...

const layer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, "HelperLayer", {
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, "path/to/helper")),
});
```